# Git lfs pull fails on osx; batch response: Expected json type, got: ""

Tags: git, macos, terminal, command-line-interface, git-lfs

I can retrieve the files fine on my windows system but I receive the following error in the terminal on my mac:

```
batch response: Expected json type, got: ""
```

Is there something I have missed setting up lfs on my mac? 
(Lfs itself was setup using 'brew install git-lfs')

Comment: Same problem here now... did you manage to solve it?